# custom tables in wordpress Database? (can i just create them with sql?)

Tags: database, sql

i just want to create a custom Table in my WordPress database and i saw many php functions to deal with that my question now is :
can i just create them with an sql command and for what do i need to keep an eye on ?

Comment: If you're not distributing code that requires the database, and are just using it for your own site, there's no reason you can't just create the database table outside of WordPress and access it with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
WPDB Class is quite beneficial in manipulating the database.

```
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/
```